# AMPscript If [EndIF] Statement Issue

Tags: ampscript, marketing-cloud

I am working on AMPScript for an email greeting for the first time. I'm trying to make it so if we don'thave a specific First Name (Preferred Guest), the default is Greetings, otherwise it should be First Name. When I run the code, the error I get is that the IF statement is not closed... but I have %%[ENDIF]%% .... Thoughts?

My code:

```
<script runat=server language=ampscript>

%%[
Var @fname

Set @fname = FirstName

]%%%%[if @fname =="Preferred Guest" then]%%
Greetings,
%%[else]%%
%%= v(@fname) =%%%%[ EndIf ]%%


</script>
```

,

Answer (score 4):

They way I'd put it would be as follows:

```
%%[ SET @greeting = IIF( FirstName == "Preferred Guest", "Greetings," FirstName ) ]%%
%%=v@(greeting)=%%
...
```

See the [function reference here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#IIf).

Comment: Also a good option.

Comment: I tend to put the IIF() all inline so I can control the whitespace.

Comment: I suppose its a matter of context. This works well in this case, the other works well in other cases.

Answer (score 2):

AMPscript does not require `<script runat=server language=ampscript>` and it's causing the send engine to freak out a bit with the opening and closing blocks etc.

Here would be a better way to write this block -

```
%%[IF FirstName =="Preferred Guest" THEN ]%%
  Greetings,
%%[ELSE]%%
  %%FirstName%%
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

You don't need to set the `FirstName` attribute to a variable - it's already available to your message as a replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax looks good, does it work though if you remove the spaces around v(@fname)?

> %%[
> Var @fname
> Set @fname = FirstName
> ]%%
>
> %%[if @fname == "Preferred Guest" then]%%

Greetings,

> %%[else]%%

%%=v(@fname)=%%

> %%[EndIf]%%